# How attach property into path.fill in template?

Tags: wpf, templates, svg

I have created controlTemplate for svg image, and I want to brush one path depending on attached property. But it doesn't work.

I ported svg into xaml:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CheckMark">
        <Viewbox Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Stretch="Uniform">
            <Canvas Name="svg12" Width="21" Height="16">
                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <Canvas.Resources/>
                <Path Name="path10" Fill="{Binding Path=(temp:CheckBoxProperties.MarkColor), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="M 8.0359499 15.742675 0.61095 8.3176751 c -0.8146 -0.8146 -0.8146 -2.1312 0 -2.9458 0.8146 -0.8146 2.1312 -0.8146 2.9458 0 L 8.0359499 9.8509748 17.277551 0.609375 c 0.8146 -0.8125 2.1313 -0.8125 2.9459 0 0.8146 0.8146001 0.8146 2.1333001 0 2.9458001 z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

And after created attached property:

```
public class CheckBoxProperties : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MarkColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "MarkColor",
            typeof(Color),
            typeof(CheckBoxProperties),
            new PropertyMetadata(ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#000000"))
        );

        public static void SetMarkColor(DependencyObject target, Color value)
        {
            target.SetValue(MarkColorProperty, value);
        }

        public static Color GetMarkColor(DependencyObject target)
        {
            return (Color)target.GetValue(MarkColorProperty);
        }
    }
```

Initialized it:

```
<UserControl Template="{StaticResource CheckMark}"
             Width="{Binding FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource WidthConverter}}"
             Height="{Binding FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}}"
             temp:CheckBoxProperties.MarkColor="#000000"/>
```

And finally it's transparent. And I have no idea why.
Actually I am beginner in wpf and it can have very simple solution

Comment: Fill is a brush you have a color. typeof(Color). Path inherits from shape, which has the fill property. Check out the type of that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shapes.shape.fill?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: public System.Windows.Media.Brush Fill { get; set; }

Comment: It helped, thnx)))